# Odd bug in string.strip() using python 2.7 and 3.5

Tags: python, string, strip

I am getting some very odd result on a quite simple string manipulation using string.strip(). I am wondering whether it's a problem that affects only me (something is wrong with my python installations?) or it's a common bug?

The bug is very wired and here it goes:

```
>>> a = './omqbEXPT.pool'
>>> a.strip('./').strip('.pool')
'mqbEXPT' #the first 'o' is missing!!!
```

It occurs only if an 'o' is following './' !

```
>>> a = './xmqbEXPT.pool'
>>> a.strip('./').strip('.pool')
'xmqbEXPT'
```

What's going on here?!
I have tested this on both python 2.7 and 3.5 and the result doesn't change.

Comment: Not a bug, please read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip).

Comment: You are right.. my bad.. I have been using strip() for a long time without fully understand it. That was the first time I have noticed that behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how the [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) method is actually designed to work.

> The chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed.
>
> The chars argument is not a prefix or suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped:

So when you say `my_string.strip('.pools')`, it's going to remove all leading and trailing characters in that set (ie. `{'.', 'p', 'o', 'l', 's'}`).

You probably want to use [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) or [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub).

```
>>> './omqbEXPT.pool'.replace('./', '').replace('.pool', '')
'omqbEXPT'

>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'^\.\/|\.pool$', '', './omgbEXPT.pool')
'omqbEXPT'
```

Answer (score 0):

string.strip() will left-strip and right-strip **per character**. Meaning, when you ask it to strip `pool`, it will remove any `p`s or `o`s or `l`s it finds on the 2 ends of the string. This is why it's stripping off the `o`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug. `strip` strips *any* charater that is in a string passed as an argument to it. So first you strip all leading and trailing dots and slashes from string `a`, and then all characters that string `'.pool'` consists of.